# Как запустить контейнер в docker-compose и передать ему параметр после запуска

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Есть три контейнера, объединённых через `docker-compose`

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: tester
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - pgadmin
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust # allow all connections without a password. This is *not* recommended for prod
    volumes:
      - c:/data_talks_club/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
  
volumes:
  database-data:
```

Есть `Dockerfile` в котором лежит python скрипт, который принимает на вход параметры.

```
FROM python:3.9.1

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install wget
RUN  apt-get install python3-psycopg2
RUN pip install pandas sqlalchemy psycopg2

WORKDIR /csv_uploader

COPY upload-data.py upload-data.py

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "upload-data.py" ]
```

Запускается он так

```
upload-data.py --login=root --password=ppp
```

Как запустить этот скрипт?

ps.
Изначально `postgres` и `pgadmin` я запускал вместе, а `Dockerfile` отдельно. Из `Dockerfile` не было доступа в БД потому что в разных сетях, поэтому решил объединить их в один compose.

Я билдил Dockerfile

```
docker build -t taxi_uploader:v001 .
```

и передавал ему параметры

```
docker run taxi_uploader:v001 --login=root --password=root
```

Answer (score 1):

Если --login и --password с момента билда никогда не будут изменяться, то укажите их в инструкции [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Если вы хотите иметь возможность изменять эти опции без ребилда, то поместите их в [переменные окружения](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) сервиса app, а в скрипте читайте их.